# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') is showing

Tags: typeerror

[The type error shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxwJg.png)

[HTML file of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf2LW.png)

This is the (Java Script File) for which I got the typeerror

```
//GETELEMENTBYID
// Accessing the H1 tag dynamically and changing the colour

var ht = document.getElementById('hd1');
ht.style.color='white';
ht.style.backgroundColor='grey';

//Changing the text of the contents

var p1 = document.getElementById('para1');
p1.innerText='Java Script is kinda tough';

/* GETELEMENTSBYCLASSNAME
Changing the colour of list items */

var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list1');
console.log(list);
list[0].style.backgroundColor='gray'; // We have to specifically mention the item index for styling, else it'd show error.

for(var i = 0 ; i<= list.length; i++){
    list[i].style.color='white';  
}
```

Inside the for loop at line of code [21], it is showing the error which I had attached in the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start at 0. Array.length is the human readable form of the length.

So `arr = [0,1,2, 3,4]` has length of 5.
But `arr[5]` is out of bounds.
In the for loop you loop till `i<=arr.length` which gives you undefined.
Remove the `=` to loop all elements and not more.

Comment: Thank you so much brother, really appreciate your help (error is gone). Is there any thank you / helpful button or something?

Comment: just upvote answers that work

Comment: @Brent, thank you. It seems I can't upvote as I'm new to this site and need at least 15 rep points. I will surely do it once I get the points.

Comment: no worries! Its all good

Answer (score 0):

When working with arrays it's common to use i < the length of the array. However, if you prefer to keep the '=' sign. You can do i <= array length - 1
:)

```js
// GETELEMENTBYID
// Accessing the H1 tag dynamically and changing the colour

var ht = document.getElementById('hd1');
ht.style.color='white';
ht.style.backgroundColor='grey';

//Changing the text of the contents


var p1 = document.getElementById('para1');
p1.innerText='Java Script is kinda tough';

/* GETELEMENTSBYCLASSNAME
Changing the colour of list items */

var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list1');
console.log(list);
list[0].style.backgroundColor='gray'; // We have to specifically mention the item index for styling, else it'd show error.

for(var i = 0 ; i < list.length; i++){
    list[i].style.color='white';  
}
```

Code should work now :D.